# Why is my mySQL throwing "ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

Error Recieved:

> `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE servers (
    serverID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    serverPrefix varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    captchaEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    giveawayEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    pollsEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    reactRolesEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    serverStatsEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    storyTimeEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    suggestionsEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    welcomeEnabled boolean NOT NULL,
    captchaChannelID varchar(20),
    storyTimeChannelID varchar(20),
    suggestionsChannelID varchar(20),
    reportChannelID varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (serverID)
);

CREATE TABLE welcomeMessage(
    welcomeMessageID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    serverID varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    `description` varchar(300), 
    instruction varchar(300), 
    footer varchar(100), 
    welcomeChannelID varchar(20), 
    DM boolean NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (welcomeMessageID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (`serverID`) REFERENCES servers (`serverID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

The error is being thrown on "CREATE TABLE welcomeMessage". I tried separating the create from the foreign key using:

```
ALTER TABLE welcomeMessage ADD FOREIGN KEY (`serverID`) REFERENCES servers(`serverID`);
```

However it just creates the table then throws the error on the "Alter" line instead.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: PLEASE, always show us ALL the error message, not a bit or a summary. There is normally something useful in all parts of an error message

Comment: Maybe it's because you're specifying InnoDB only for welcomeMessage and not for servers?

Comment: My bet on this one is because you didn't specify the table engine for the servers table which defaults to MYISAM

Comment: @JeffHolt beat me to it :D

Comment: Bet your default database type is MYISAM !! See above ^^^^ for additional info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the charset and the collation. For the foreign key to be well-formed, both the parent and the child columns must have the same charset and collation. The first statement relies on the default settings, while the second has explicit settings. If those are different from the defaults, a failure occurs.

Your code works if I just comment out the `charset .... collate ...` part of the second `create table` statement, as you can see [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc84a9a0952778c6418e3aab78b31c7d).

Both storage engines also need to be aligned. If your database uses MyISAM as a default engine, the code won’t work either (as the second statement explicitly uses InnoDB).

Comment: Thank you so much. I added it to the server table as its needed to store some of the data. Didnt know they had to be the same. Appreciate it :)